# How does 5NF work with original table with ID Column

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

Came across an interesting problem while I was studying about normal forms, but I could not find an answer anywhere because most examples I've seen do not use any Id columns, they use the typical Supplier, Producer, Consumer pattern. Suppose I have a table called customer with the following schema:

```
Customer(ID: int [PK], Name: varchar(100), Address: varchar(100), Picture: varchar(100));
```

If I was to normalize this table form to 5NF I am thinking it would look like this:

```
CustomerName(Id:int [PK], Name: varchar(100)); 

CustomerAddress(Id:int [PK], Address: varchar(100)); 

CustomerPicture(Id:int [PK], Address: varchar(100));
```

Now this does satisfy 5NF because I can join back these tables into the original table without any data loss, but is this actually right? It just seems silly to me because If I wanted all information about a Customer, I would have to write a query with multiple joins, and joins are expensive, performance wise. Have I decomposed this table properly? I feel like I may have missed something.

Comment: The example you show doesn't have anything to do with 5NF. You have a customer with three attribute columns. You haven't described any relationship between those columns that would require splitting the table. In other words, the candidate key (`id`) is sufficient, because we assume the other three columns are dependent only on that candidate key. I don't see any reason to split the table into three tables, because the original table is already in 5NF.

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--you may find mistakes that make your question unnecessary & we don't know exactly what algorithm you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Ids are just values. Whatever you want to do, apply the definitions & rules as you would for any value. PS If there are no other FDs or JDs than the ones from that CK then those are 5NF but so is your original table. You don't seem to know what 5NF is, and you haven't justified anything according to definitions, theorems & proven algorithms. Addressing your question right now is to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke example. That is too broad. And not productive--because it's just another presentation for you to misunderstand. Show your work following the one you have.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned any functional or join dependencies so it's impossible to come to any conclusion about 5NF from your example. Also your pseudo-code suggests a table where all the columns except id may be nullable but 5NF deals with relations which permit only values, not nulls.

Let's say you have a relation variable, Customer, with attributes: id,name,address,picture. Given the following functional dependency:

{id}→{name,address,picture}

If the only join dependencies satisfied by Customer are those implied by the above FD then we can conclude that id is the only candidate key of Customer and that Customer satisfies 5NF because all its JDs are implied by keys.

I think you are suggesting substituting numbers in place of name,address and picture and making those attributes foreign keys. If the same dependencies apply in Customer after you make such a change then that change makes absolutely no difference to whether Customer satisfies 5NF or not. Normalization is not concerned with data types (numbers or strings) and is not altered by whether attributes are foreign keys or not.

Normalization has nothing to do with performance but in the case just described there's no normalization-related reason to create new tables referenced foreign keys. Doing so seems to add to logical complexity of the database because it may mean extra joins are required. On the other hand the additional tables might be useful if they remove a potentially undesirable insertion anomaly by letting you create names, addresses and pictures without a corresponding row in customer - assuming that makes sense in some given situation.